# Outlook 2016 View Plain Text Email in Font like Courier

Tags: fonts, microsoft-office-2016, courier

I want to view all plain text email messages in a font like courier where each letter takes the same amount of space. (Computer generated reports are a mess to look at otherwise.) Anyone know how to change this setting in Office 2016?

Comment: Real questions are: a) Why in the name of Bill Gates is Tinyflacid, I mean Microsoft, defaulting to (or even allowing) a proportionally spaced font for  "Plain Text" Format e-mails (presumably since Outlook started in 1992)?!?  Any jr. IT guy born  before ~1990 prolly knows that Plain Text Format is for emulating font used prior to GUI / WYSIWIG apps which (even if they differed in style and size) were *ALL - FIXED - SPACED*!?!  b) How can we change that default (i.e. for all users within an Enterprise, so our app-generated log / error e-mails line up without having to use HTML format).

Comment: You make a great point Tom.

Answer (score 14):

Yea! Finally found it. Go to: File, Options, Mail, Signatures and Stationary, Composing and reading plain text messages, Font. Then select a font like Courier New. Now my computer generated reports look beautiful again! (Well, sort of. Kind of hard to get too poetic over plain text. :-)

Credit to: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=52016#font-size-reading-pane

Comment: +1 Unbelievable! I wouldn't have expected that option under _Stationary_.

Comment: Update: in my version of Outlook the option is under: File, Options, Mail, (in the "Compose message" section) click on "Stationery and Fonts..." button, then in the popup window click on the "Font..." button in the "Composing and reading plain text messages" section (last section).

Comment: Thanks! but it makes me wonder - Why is it even necessary to have to do this?....